# error in fcl library: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object

Tags: c++

I installed the [lbccd](https://github.com/danfis/libccd) library in order to use [Fcl](https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl) library but I cannot compile fcl.

When I run from terminal cmake, it says that there's no package libccd even I installed and compiled this library.

Moreover when I compile with make this error appears:

> relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a
>   shared object; recompile with -fPIC.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the message says and compiling with -fPIC?

Comment: I read about it but I'm not an expert and I didn't understand how to use it. Could you explain me how to use it?